# raspberry in the middle

Tags: communication

I have a pc that can communicate to broader intranet,  but it now must also connect to LINUX server that is its own network via RJ45 ( wired LAN ).  The Raspberry could communicate to the special network on the LAN ( have to use REST calls) but I need to issue pass through commands to the raspberry ( or middle device ). I didn't really see USB being discussed. I also wondered if the PC and Raspberry could write to a memory card.  Suggestions. The throughput doesn't have to be terrific and the file or packet size isn't huge either ( 1KB of data ) or less.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. How is the RasPi connected to the intranet? By wifi? You say there is no problem to connect to the linux server by wired LAN. Where is the problem? What are REST calls? What do you mean with pass through commands and middle device? What's about USB and what's the issue for writing to memory card?

Comment: I don't have a raspberry PI at this point as I don't know if it would solve my problem. As I understand it, if I hook my computer up to the private network I have lost contact with the larger internet. I am certain I can connect a raspberry to the private network but now I have to tell the pc to issue a REST command to connect to the private network. How do I contact / communicate to the raspberry ? rs232, GPIO, USB or ??? to be the proxy between the PC and the private network

Comment: Usually you can connect to two networks at the same time. It is only a configuration issue on the computer. You do not need a RasPi for it. The most common connection to a RasPi is by wifi or wired ethernet.

Comment: Thanks I will look into 2 NIC cards on a computer and how that works ....